# What is the type of the keyboard event for TextInput in React-Native and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm not able to find this anywhere. I have code like this:

```js
const Component = () => {

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    const key = event.nativeEvent.key.toLowerCase();
    console.log({key});
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        ...
    />
  )
}
```

What is the type of `event` parameter? In ReactJS I would use `KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>` what is the equivalent in React-Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **NativeSyntheticEvent** and **TextInputKeyPressEventData**

```
const handleKeyPress = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>) => {
const key = event.nativeEvent.key.toLowerCase();
console.log({ key });
```

Comment: Thanks, just found this by adding the wrong type and got it from the error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
const handleKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent<TextInput>) => {
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: This is an invalid type. The `KeyboardEvent` is part of React and it will not work for React Native. Try it, it will give a TypeScript error about an invalid type and it will show you what is the proper type in the error message.